# Websphere core class file

Tags: websphere, weblogic

I am Websphere support person and I got a question from my colleague. In Weblogic weblogic.Server is the class which get executed while running the JVM similarly what is the class file getting excuted in Websphere. I am not sure about it, can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is `com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer`. You can find it in the admin console: Application Servers -> (select server) -> Process Definition, look for "Executable Target".